# How to unit test asp.net identity extended functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, moq

I extended my User class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public bool Blocked { get; set; }
}
```

and wrote a method:

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
public ActionResult Ban(string id)
{
      var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
      var user = context.Users.Find(id);
      if(user.Blocked)
      {
         user.Blocked = false;
      }
      else
      {
         user.Blocked = true;
      }
     context.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("ViewUsers", "Admin");
     }
```

How can I test it using Moq?

Also I've no idea how to test this method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ActionResult ViewUsers()
{
    var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var users = from u in context.Users
                   where u.Roles.Any(r => r.Role.Name == "user")
                   select u;
    ViewBag.Users = users;
    return View(users.ToList());
    }
```

I've tried to mock ApplicationDbContext or UserManager, but I think I don't know something important. Thank you.

Comment: you need to inject your context if you want to mock it, you're currently newing it up within the method.